# Where can I find documentation for the zii and zii jui widgets?

Tags: yii, widget

I'm trying to use the zii and zii jui widget extensions from Yii. Unfortunately I've found documentation on the widgets (e.g. CJuiAutoComplete, CJuiDatePicker, etc.) to be sparse. I'd like to have a list of all the parameters that can be passed to the widgets, which are required, and how they are used. For example, what does the 'name' field, is it required, and what is the expected format of the field? What about 'attribute', 'value', 'showAnim', 'options', and 'htmlOptions'? I've guessed at a few of them based on a few examples but I'd like to have a good understanding of those fields. Also, how do I animate the search for autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `CJuiXXXX` widget is a jQuery UI widget, which means that you can find a complete documentation for each and every one at the [jQuery UI site](http://jqueryui.com/demos).

CJuiDatepicker is [datePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), CJuiAutoComplete is [autoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) etc.

- `name` will be rendered as the `name` value of the input `<input type="text" name="NAME">`
- `value` is the initial value of the element
- `showAnim` and everything that goes in the `options` array are the options of the specific plugin. For the list of available options for each plugin, check the jQuery UI site.
- `htmlOptions` are just that, options that will be rendered in HTML. For instance, if the `htmlOptions` array is `array('class'=>'blue', 'style'=>'color:red;', 'id'=>'element')` then the HTML element will have a `blue` css class, an explicit style of `color:red` and `element` for it's id.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I had figured out most of what you said and had taken a look at the jQuery documentation. Name, value, attribute, source, etc. are not part of the jQuery widget.  Where is the documentation for them? Are there others I may be missing?

Comment: Like I said, `name` and `value` are just HTML attributes, `source` is explained at [CJuiAutoComplete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiAutoComplete).